# Virtual domains and subdomains using mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, dns, subdomain

I would like to create a service where a user either can get a subdomain or a regular domain on my service.

The idea is that all subdomains except `www.` should go to `/subdomains.php?user=[sub]&url=[requestet url]`

And all domains except my own 2 domains should go to `/domain.php?url=$1`

My 2 domains are:
`domain1.com` and `domain2.se`

I've tried the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite sub domains.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain2\.se$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.domain2\.se$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomain.php?user=%2&url=$1 [QSA,L]

#Rewrite 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain2\.se$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain1.com/domain.php?url=$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But it does not seen to work.

Comment: What happens? Which parts work, which don't? Is the module enabled? Do basic other redirections work?

Answer (score 0):

Sub domains: how do you expect an URL to be *both* a subdomain of `domain1.com` and `domain2.se` at the same time?

Try e.g. this simplification:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(domain1\.com|domain2\.se)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.(domain1\.com|domain2\.se)$ [NC]
```